# Listview Updating, jQueryMoble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, listview

I am trying to update or replace a list and keep the styles that were present before the update. Reading form the jQuerymoble website it says that the refresh() method call only works on new nodes. I am using the .html call to update the list and not .append. I am not sure if that is where I am having problems but the refresh call is not working in any case. My new list does not have the correct styles. I am using .html because many nodes are removed/added at the same time so append would not really work in my case.

Sample Code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#quicksearch").keyup(function() {
                     $.getJSON(search,function(data){
                          newlistcode= data //formatted correctly for a new list
                          $(“ul”).html(newlistcode);

                          $(“ul”).listview(‘refresh’);
                          });
                });
        });

</script>



<div data-demo-html="true">
<ul data-role="listview" class="list" id="listview1">
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$(“#listview1”).html(newlistcode);

$(“listview1”).listview(‘refresh’);
```

to

```
$(“#listview1”).append(newlistcode);

$(“#listview1”).listview(‘refresh’);
```

Where

```
newlistcode = '<li><a>content</a></li>';
```

Comment: I have added more information to the question to try and be more specific. I was unable to us the .live() function to make it work. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user2918595 updated my answer based on your question edit.  Try using append and then call refresh.

Comment: My imports were wrong... I appreciate the help! It works now.